# Angular: Is it possible to add routing instructions to the routing module automatically when a component is generated?

Tags: angular

I've used the following command

```
ng generate module customers --route customers --module app.module
```

this generates a customers component and add its rounting instructions automatically to customers module's routing file...
Now I want to generate additional components and I expected the routing instructions to be added automatically but it's not the case.. Is it possible to add routing instructions automatically to the routing module when a component is generated?

Comment: how are you generating the additional components, what command are you using?

Comment: @PierreDuc ng g c componentname

Comment: how would the angular cli know that you are creating a route component? It could be any component. And no, unfortunately there is no option yet to add route components directly